# How to identify which port in graphics card to connect to USB-C Link for oculus quest

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, adapter, usb-c

I have a PC with Geforce RTX 2070 video card which seems to have 3 ports. I have an Oclus Quest which specifies [specs](https://www.oculus.com/quest/accessories/) for its USB-C Link cable for wired connection to the PC. Whats my best option for connecting this to the graphics card? I will need an adapter for either DVI, HDMI or the last port to USB-C. Which port is the best to use, and which adapter is best to get to connect to the Oculus Link cable?

[Picture of the graphics card and 3 ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCkd7.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure adapters to plain video ports will work? I'm pretty sure VR headsets need two-way communication, they send sensor data back to PC over USB. IIRC Quest is quite picky about its USB-C cables.

Comment: I have no idea, hope to get some information if this is possible with asking here. Is there enough information on the specs page for the oculus quest to answer this?

Comment: Well, the photo on the page you've linked clearly shows a USB-C to USB-C cable. It also specifies that it needs a "USB 3.2 gen 1 type C" cable, not a USB-to-video cable. Buy the official one if you want to avoid headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oculus quest doesn't use a native video signal from your GPU. Instead, it uses software on your PC to convert the video data into a data stream and send it over USB to the headset. You can just use a USB A to USB C adapter to use it on a normal desktop PC as long as you have an actual USB 3.0 port.

Edit: There's also [an entry](https://support.oculus.com/444256562873335/) on the official Oculus support pages.